# "group by" functionality in azure-cosmosdb-java

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

I want to perform "group-by" operation in a cosmos-db collection using java.

But as this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions) shows this feature ('group by') is still under active development and not yet supported.

What I want is something like

```
SELECT SUM(some_attribute) FROM collection_name GROUP BY grouping_attribute
```

Is there some way to achieve the same functionality?

Only way I could think of is to execute multiple queries for each grouping_attribute item like

```
SELECT VALUE SUM(some_attribute) FROM collection_name WHERE grouping_attribute = 'some_value'
```

The github repo for "azure-cosmos-db" does shows an [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/rx/examples/InMemoryGroupbyTest.java) for group by but that is InMemory and not executed server side.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: @mentallurg I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi,Vasu. If my answer helps you,you could mark it to end this case.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JayGong There are other answers that point to the same library and that is pretty old - the last commit was 4 years ago. I would like to wait and see if someone else has a different approach

Comment: @VasuBansal Ok,sure.Also,maybe submitting feedback or contacting with azure team are more effective way.Have a good day!

Comment: @JayGong I already contacted the cosmosDB team, lets see if and when they reply

Comment: @VasuBansal Any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

As you seen,the `group by` feature is currently in active development still,so nothing could be found from official document,except custom implements.

I provide a working custom package which implements aggregate features for cosmos db,named [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize).

You could load `cube.string` as a stored procedure, then you call it with an aggregation configuration.

```
{cubeConfig: {groupBy: "grouping_attribute", field: "some_attribute", f: "sum"}}
```